# Как получить исходный код страницы в переменную PHP

Tags: php, curl

Пробовал функции file_get_contents и curl - не работает именно с сайтом [adidas.ru](http://adidas.ru).

Раньше все отлично работало через cURL, но сейчас не работает.
Возможно, они заблокировали мой IP?

```
function curl($url, $postdata) {
$uagent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1"; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, ""); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 $content = curl_exec( $ch );
 curl_close( $ch ); 
 return $content;

}

echo curl('http://www.adidas.ru/search','q=');
```

До этого код работал пол года без проблем. Если вместо adidas написать reebok, все работает.

Действительно ошибка HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
Но почему? Если заходить через браузер, то открывает без проблем.
Как можно получить код страницы?

Comment: Не понятно... Вы хотите, чтобы мы Вам предложили готовое решение? Это так не работает. Приведите свой код и опишите что по-вашему не работает.

Comment: Напишите что конкретно у вас не работает? За вас никто писать не будет! Но экстрасенсы мне подсказывают, что дело возможно в том, что товары на странице загружаются ajax запросом

Comment: `HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden` ни о чём не говорит?

Comment: > https://www.adidas.ru/
РАБОТА САЙТА И МОБИЛЬНОГО ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ ОСТАНОВЛЕНА ДО ДАЛЬНЕЙШЕГО УВЕДОМЛЕНИЯ

Answer (score 1):

сайту нужны какие-то куки. например, у меня после добавления к вашему коду чего-то подобного (значение взял из `firebug` в браузере)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Cookie:dwac_bfgL2iaagIFBaaaadT2cF99ObL=Q_oa325yGUdRU2S0mnm4GKEv5CWwAYwro3k%3D|demandaaglru|||RUB|false|Etc%2FGMT%2D3|true; cqcid=acjUV4UWLDS4F6B9VO1aKEWWnp; sid=Q_oa325yGUdRU2S0mnm4GKEv5CWwAYwro3k; pagecontext_geo_country=UA; dwanonymous_cf44e4f9b635e8943650a805c7ab4242=acjUV4UWLDS4F6B9VO1aKEWWnp; pagecontext_logged_in=""; pagecontext_customer_id=acjUV4UWLDS4F6B9VO1aKEWWnp; lastVisitedProducts=""; dwsid=11SWv08zZ1_iD5_vXC3QljWBaEWRQPIzECWPaO-djQKhtX4nhs_Xg1s5aMMYJr90F7NV2uklpztal2y8YsWsjQ==; LastPageUpdateTimestamp=1464124623709; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1464124623859r0.30954379713645497; optimizelySegments=%7B%22299577001%22%3A%22direct%22%2C%22299649707%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22299754438%22%3A%22false%22%2C%22299765888%22%3A%22opera%22%2C%22655644525%22%3A%22true%22%7D; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%225885940669%22%3A%225872951618%22%7D; _ym_uid=146412462540490344; _ym_isad=1; _ym_visorc_7857334=w; __cq_uuid=da803170-21f4-11e6-aa9c-fd8d2eed77ab; PrevPageURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.adidas.ru%2Fsearch; UserSignUpAndSave=2; ak_bmsc=5D8D5ADA817A1830D669EF612B47DD67170E5ECBF7140000C9C4445710CC116A~plOv26rMgrLkyJGa1jeI+acE7yC/zZ5DcnEFrz/AB0FIwJYdSZhJuYAEBnm1Z3W98XqL+ZwOhMskLVVzf5YaC4mk/t2OXyTQ0ezU6stQZz0L4EsEs3XBzWNZ2QdZzcCnaNNYsW/7SuFd7VslgkmgAmh+bspaIMYSpWq7k5oQvau5o=; onesite_language=ru; onesite_country=RU; onesite_market=RU; geolocatedRegionOrCity=Moscow; us_criteo_sociomantic_split=criteo; __adi_rt_DkpyPh8=CTRLH2H; _ga=GA1.2.520746757.1464124634; RES_TRACKINGID=866314134161171; ResonanceSegment=1; RES_SESSIONID=347364828772007; _gat_tealium_0=1; AMCV_7ADA401053CCF9130A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=283337926%7CMCMID%7C02420446016253062430521925596725595527%7CMCAAMLH-1464729434%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1464729434%7CNRX38WO0n5BH8Th-nqAG_A%7CMCAID%7CNONE; s_cc=true; optimizelyPendingLogEvents=%5B%5D; s_sq=ag-adi-global-prod%252Cag-adi-ru-prod%3D%2526c.%2526a.%2526activitymap.%2526page%253DPLP%25257CSEARCH%2526link%253Dclose%2526region%253DBODY%2526pageIDType%253D1%2526.activitymap%2526.a%2526.c%2526pid%253DPLP%25257CSEARCH%2526pidt%253D1%2526oid%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.adidas.ru%25252Fsearch%252523%2526ot%253DA; s_tps=23; s_pvs=33; s_pers=%20s_vnum%3D1464728400393%2526vn%253D1%7C1464728400393%3B%20pn%3D1%7C1466716634407%3B%20c4%3DPLP%257CSEARCH%7C1464126457318%3B%20s_visit%3D1%7C1464126457321%3B%20s_invisit%3Dtrue%7C1464126457323%3B; _gali=simpleSearchFormRedesign; customer_hashed_email_pers=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e; utag_main=v_id:0154e4a0ef8f00206d14dbe5f35204076001b06e00bd0$_sn:1$_ss:1$_pn:1%3Bexp-session$_st:1464126458567$ses_id:1464124632975%3Bexp-session$search_data:SEARCH-QUERY%7CA%7CA%3Bexp-1466716658550; searchQuery=a; RT="nu=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.adidas.ru%2Fsearch&dm=adidas.ru&si=1fb6c943-f0b1-4668-9e59-b8465ab274c5&ss=1464124622069&sl=1&tt=11023&obo=0&sh=1464124634779%3D1%3A0%3A11023&cl=1464124650728&bcn=%2F%2F364bf52c.mpstat.us%2F&r=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.adidas.ru%2Fsearch&ul=1464124658585"' ));
```

вернуло страницу. дальше сами разбирайтесь, какие куки, как их прикручивать.

также на будущее - при возникновении подобных проблем, что обычно следует сделать в первую очередь

1) глянуть, что возвращает [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-error.php)

2) открываете `firebug`, вкладка `Network`, на сайте в строку поиска вводите что нибудь, жмете `Enter`. в списке страниц, к которым пошли запросы, ищете нужную (в вашем случае `search?q=a`), во вкладке `Headers` ищете `Request headers`. В 90% случаев ваша проблема в том, что вы не отправляете какие-либо `HTTP` заголовки, которые отправляются при визите через браузер. А дальше просто подставляете все заголовки из браузера в ваш запрос (обратите внимание на `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` для `curl`) и исследуете.